# Class/model level property on ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I create a class level attribute or constant on ember-data? In addition, how do I call it then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
    color: DS.attr()
});

App.Color.reopenClass({
  foo:4
});

alert(App.Color.foo);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lucemocoso/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: What if you're using Ember-cli? And it's just `export default DS.Model.extend({`

Comment: var model = DS.Model.extend({ ... }); model.reopenClass({ ... }); export default model;